# Hibernate generate table in Postgre from SpringBoot MultiModuleProject

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have created a SpringBoot multi module project.

You can find the basic projectstructure [here](https://pastebin.com/BTk45BRB).

Now I'm trying to generate tables using Hibernate in the model-module.

**Prerequisites:**

database in docker environment:

```
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=user -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

model/pom.xml:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <!--general-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--persistence-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

model/src/main/resources/application-model.properties:

```
# spring datasource
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user

# hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

model/src/main/java/model/ModelConfig.java:

```
...
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.test.model.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-model.properties")
public class ModelConfig {
}
```

model/src/main/java/model/MyEntity.java:

```
...
@Entity
@Data
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String text;
}
```

web/src/main/java/web/WebConfig.java:

```
...
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test.*")
public class WebConfig {
}
```

WebConfig is a configurationclass which right next to the WebApplication.java which has the main-function of the application.
So the `@ComponentScan("com.test.*")` in WebConfig should scan in com.test.model as well and find the ModelConfig bean, which in fact is the case:

[image]
taken from Intellij

In ModelConfig the annotation `@EntityScan("com.test.model.*")` should search for entities in com.test.model.*, which is the case for MyEntity.java.

**Error:**

Actually there is no error, `#mvn clean install` runs and builds everything and I can run the application without getting any error messages as you can see [in the output](https://pastebin.com/8kB0iUBB).
**But there is no table generated.**

**Expectations:**

I expect this setup to generate a table called <my_entity>, with a id-field with autogeneration and a field called text with varchar(255), which are the defaults of `@GeneratedValue` and `@Column` in MyEntity.java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try removing the componentscan, springboot would automatically find your entities

Comment: that didnt help, becouse it seems to scan only components from its own module... however i found the issue, it was in the @EntityScan("com.test.model.*") but the param should be "com.test.model", this fixed the problem